# Physics Colliders Explode Array of Blocks Prematurely

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm starting to play with collision physics in Blender 2.82 and have created the test array of blocks that can be downloaded from

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMamDjInBclLC0ebdKVlnSzI_K7b8Wqq

Problem is that the array explodes immediately after Blender calculates the first frame. I've tried several different physics settings and have researched the net - both to no avail.

I suspect this has something to do with the *Array* modifier. Can someone tell me how fix this?

Comment: please share the blend file via stack exchange or make sure the link you send is available publicly.
Also try to include the screenshots of the issue.

As for as I know the collision doesn't work on array.
You should apply the modifier and make the block as separate objects.
and also has to make sure the origin is center of each object.

Answer (score 1):

I did not allow enough space between blocs.